# Disjoint matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying matrix product algorithms. I've seen that there is a concept of disjoint matrix multiplication. What does it consist in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up matrix multiplication in terms of a reduced number of elementary products, Arnold Schönhage proposed 1981 in his paper [Partial and Total Matrix Multiplication](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210032) to split the product of two matrices into several disjoint matrix multiplications. The variables in these smaller multiplications belong to separate sets, i.e. they are disjoint.

The concept is also described in Victor Pan's 1984 survey [How Can We Speed Up Matrix Multiplication](http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/vpan/pdf/PanSIAMReview84.pdf) and in Igo Kaporin's 1999 publication [A Practical Algorithm for Faster Matrix Multiplication](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/228638684_A_practical_algorithm_for_faster_matrix_multiplication).

Here is Schönhage's approximate algorithm for multiplying two 3x3 matrices:

```
# Define a very small epsilon term
# It might make sense to use a power of 2 and
# implement multiply/divide by shifts
s := 1000000000;
e := 1.0 / s;

# Maximum error for a single equation: 1E-09 = 1 x e

#
# 21 intermediate products:
#
P01 := (s * a11 + e * a12) * (e * b11 + s * b21);
P02 := (s * a21 + e * a22) * (e * b12 + s * b22);
P03 := (s * a31 + e * a32) * (e * b13 + s * b23);
P04 := (s * a11 + e * a13) * (s * b31);
P05 := (s * a21 + e * a23) * (s * b32);
P06 := (s * a31 + e * a33) * (s * b33);
P07 := (s * a11) * (s * b21 + s * b31);
P08 := (s * a21) * (s * b22 + s * b32);
P09 := (s * a31) * (s * b23 + s * b33);
P10 := (s * a11 + e * a22) * (- b12 + s * b21);
P11 := (s * a11 + e * a32) * (- b13 + s * b21);
P12 := (e * a12 + s * a21) * (- b11 + s * b22);
P13 := (s * a21 + e * a32) * (- b13 + s * b22);
P14 := (e * a12 + s * a31) * (- b11 + s * b23);
P15 := (e * a22 + s * a31) * (- b12 + s * b23);
P16 := (s * a11 + e * a23) * (b12 + s * b31);
P17 := (s * a11 + e * a33) * (b13 + s * b31);
P18 := (e * a13 + s * a21) * (b11 + s * b32);
P19 := (s * a21 + e * a33) * (b13 + s * b32);
P20 := (e * a13 + s * a31) * (b11 + s * b33);
P21 := (e * a23 + s * a31) * (b12 + s * b33);

c11 := P01 + P04 - P07;
c12 :=  - e * P04 - P08 + P12 + e * P16 + P18;
c13 :=  - e * P04 - P09 + P14 + e * P17 + P20;
c21 :=  - e * P05 - P07 + P10 + P16 + e * P18;
c22 := P02 + P05 - P08;
c23 :=  - e * P05 - P09 + P15 + e * P19 + P21;
c31 :=  - e * P06 - P07 + P11 + P17 + e * P20;
c32 :=  - e * P06 - P08 + P13 + P19 + e * P21;
c33 := P03 + P06 - P09;

#  Verify results:
#  (resulting error is not zero but rather small)
Simplify(c11 - (a11*b11 + a12*b21 + a13*b31));
Simplify(c12 - (a11*b12 + a12*b22 + a13*b32));
Simplify(c13 - (a11*b13 + a12*b23 + a13*b33));
Simplify(c21 - (a21*b11 + a22*b21 + a23*b31));
Simplify(c22 - (a21*b12 + a22*b22 + a23*b32));
Simplify(c23 - (a21*b13 + a22*b23 + a23*b33));
Simplify(c31 - (a31*b11 + a32*b21 + a33*b31));
Simplify(c32 - (a31*b12 + a32*b22 + a33*b32));
Simplify(c33 - (a31*b13 + a32*b23 + a33*b33));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the algorithm from Coppersmith and Winograd (performing a matrix product in $n^{2.37..}$ multiplications) using the concept from Schönhage ? Thank you again.

Comment: At least, they are citing Schönhage and Pan as references in "Matrix Multiplication via Arithmetic Progressions".

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the details of the algorithm from Coppersmith and Winodgrad ? Thank you again.